# How to get naive Bayes classifier to work?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes

I tried to use a Naive Bayes classifier to classify my sample corpus. The sample corpus is as follows (stored in myfile.csv):

```
"Text";"label"
“There be no significant perinephric collection";"label1”
“There be also fluid collection”;”label2”
“No discrete epidural collection or abscess be see";"label1”
“This be highly suggestive of epidural abscess”;”label2”
“No feature of spondylodiscitis be see”;”label1”
“At the level of l2 l3 there be loculated epidural fluid collection”;”label2”
```

The code for the classifier is as follows:

```
# libraries for dataset preparation, feature engineering, model training 
import pandas as pd
import csv
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

#Data preparation
data = pd.read_csv(open('myfile.csv'), sep=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

# Creating Bag of Words
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data)
print(X_train_counts.shape)

#From occurrences to frequencies
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
print(X_train_tf.shape)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
print(X_train_tfidf.shape)

#Training a classifier
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, data['label'])

#Predicting with the classifier
docs_new = ['there is no spondylodiscitis', 'there is a large fluid collection']
X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)
predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)
for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted): 
    print('%r => %s' % (doc, data['label']))
```

Whenever I try to run the prediction, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'label'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you mean `X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data['Text'])` instead of `X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data)`? I ran your code under this change and without `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` and I didn't get any error, actually I got `label1` for `'there is no spondylodiscitis'` and `label2` for `'there is a large fluid collection'`

Comment: I created manually your sample dataframe when I was trying to reproduce your error btw, that's why I didn't include the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` part.

Comment: Without QUOTE_NONE I keep getting the error: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 1

Comment: What is the output of `data.columns.values`?

Comment: I figured that removing all quotes from the .csv file and removing quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, the program works. But it still gives me the wrong answer though. How did you get the right label?

Comment: I didn't do anything, I just ran your code under the change that I mentioned before. I trained the data using the sample data provided by yourself, so I assume you have more data. That's probably why we get different results

Comment: No actually I don't have more data! That's it! Did you make any other changes? I keep getting: 'there is no spondylodiscitis' => 0    label1 and 'there is a large fluid collection' => 0    label1

Comment: I didn't run the following lines `#From occurrences to frequencies`
`tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)`
`X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)`
`print(X_train_tf.shape)` because you don't seem to be using them anywhere else

Comment: You don't use `X_train_tf` anywhere else, instead you're using `X_train_tfidf` during the fitting part

Comment: I did that, and still got the same wrong answer. Could you post your full code and answer in the 'Post you answer' section below?

Comment: Run `predicted` instead. That's the correct result

Comment: Run this instead: `for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted): 
    print('%r => %s' % (doc, category))`. You wrote `data['label']` and it should say `category` instead. The output is  `'there is no spondylodiscitis' => label1
'there is a large fluid collection' => label2`

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, load up your code in the REPL or debugger. Observe whatever is in `...` is irrelevant to your issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
...

data = pd.read_csv(open('myfile.csv'), sep=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
...
```

Now we can query the `data` object interactively:

```
(Pdb) data.keys()
Index(['"Text"', '"label"'], dtype='object')
(Pdb) data['"label"']
0    "label1”
1    ”label2”
2    "label1”
3    ”label2”
4    ”label1”
5    ”label2”
Name: "label", dtype: object
(Pdb) data["label"]
*** KeyError: 'label'
```

Note that the keys are `'"Test"'` and `'"label"'`, not `"Test"` and `"label"`. So you can't do `data["label"]`, or you'll get the `KeyError` that you're seeing. You have to say `data['"label"']`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your data has quotes, why have you got QUOTE_NONE specified there?

Comment: That is probably the correct answer - using `"label"` instead or turning quotes on will probably help. This answer would be more helpful if you'd say how to do it correctly though (otherwise it's rather a comment). E.g. by quoting the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Without QUOTE_NONE I keep getting the error: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 1

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be able to access pandas column with `data['label']` ,
your first line should be :

```
Text;label
```

not this :

```
"Text";"label"
```

this way you have to index your label col like this ;

```
data['"label"']
```

which is not looks fine